# Correct way to reuse ADODB.Command

Tags: vbscript, adodb

What is the correct way to call a sproc within a loop?

If I come in with something like this:

```
Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
DO UNTIL RS.EOF
    SET cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = Connection
    cmd.CommandText = "spMySproc"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter ("@p1",adInteger,adParamInput, ,RS("Val1"))
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter ("@p2",adInteger,adParamInput, ,RS("Val2"))
    cmd.Execute
    SET cmd = nothing
LOOP
```

Then on the second and subsequent iterations of the loop I get an error

> Procedure or function spMySproc has too many arguments specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to separate command preparation and the loop. Then you can use Parameters collection multiple times to execute the command.

```
'preparing command
Set cmd = CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = Connection
    cmd.CommandText = "spMySproc"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@p1", adInteger, adParamInput,,0) '0 as placeholder
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@p2", adInteger, adParamInput,,0) '0 as placeholder

Do Until Rs.Eof
    cmd.Parameters("@p1").Value = Rs("Val1").Value
    cmd.Parameters("@p2").Value = Rs("Val2").Value
    cmd.Execute
    Rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: That looks reasonable, but I am completely baffled: When I run that example `cmd` never gets a value.  If I inspect it in the Script Editor its value remains `Empty` the entire time, even as I step over the lines setting it and its properties!  (And I get error 424: Object required when I try to Execute it.)  Is there something weird with scoping I need to account for?

Comment: @feetwet you can remove `Set cmd = Nothing` if you are not done with `cmd`.

Comment: @feetwet Whenever I see this pattern I shudder, what possible reason could you have for executing database calls in a loop? Most reasons people give can be done more efficiently by re-thinking the problem and adjusting the approach.

Comment: @Lankymart - In this case for each input value I have to insert rows, invoke an HTTP PUT and send one or more Emails.  I can't configure this particular database to send mail due to infrastructure constraints, so given that circumstance I'm already stuck using scripting with loops.

Comment: @Feetwet As I thought you should re-think the problem but hey legacy is legacy I guess. Problem is using "it's legacy" as an excuse just leads to systems running inefficiently coded systems for years and years, until someone takes the dive.

Comment: @Lankymart - Exactly.  If someone told me five years ago I'd be patching an ASP Classic system in 2016 I would have cried.  But since there's more work than there is time or money, I've just gotten used to crying ;)

Comment: I figured out how to get this example working: It's important to note that for my ADODB.Connection I only did `CreateObject`.  Apparently that's a different scope than `Server.CreateObject`, so if I try to do the latter on the ADODB.Command it fails to actually create the object!

Comment: @feetwet this code just **works**, you must do something different which we don't know? please show us what's your final work. BTW there is no scope differences between the objects created with `CreateObject` or `Server.CreateObject`.

Comment: As a stand-alone VBScript, if I run commandline or wscript with `Server.CreateObject`, I get a Windows Script Host error `Object required: 'Server'`.  (You did answer the original question, so I was going to mark this "Answered," but not with this remaining confusion.)

Comment: @feetwet Then [This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/06/01/whats-the-difference-between-wscript-createobject-server-createobject-and-createobject/) will help you to understand the differences between `CreateObjects`'s.

Comment: Actually that article confuses me more.  I'm *guessing* that Server. doesn't exist for WScript?

Comment: @feetwet [Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525541%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is an ASP (IIS) object, has a [Server.CreateObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524786%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method. [WScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at5ydy31%28v%3Dvs.84%29.aspx) is the root object of Windows Script Host, has also a [WScript.CreateObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzysf6hc%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method. Except those there is VBScript's built-in [CreateObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcw63t7z%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method. still confused?